# How do I get a list of settings in which settings should grouped by an ID in Hibernate.find()

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, spring-orm

I have a settings table in which there are multiple settings. This table has a column "**idss**". I want to get all the results grouped by this "idss". So I am expecting a **List** which will contain single unique entries as well as entries having common *"idss" grouped into a list*. Please help me on how to do this.

Something like

```
 List<Settings>
    -> List<Setting> ( explanation : idss=1, List<Setting> has one setting )
    -> List<Setting> ( explanation : idss=2, List<Setting> has two setting with common idss )
    -> List<Setting> ( explanation : idss=3, List<Setting> has four setting with common idss )
```

I **am using find() method form the hibernate template using spring orm**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the desired output structure directly from JPA or SQL. You can however read the data flat using order by idss and built-up the desired structure while iterating over the result set.